# Twitter Typeahead Ajax results undefined

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, typeahead

I'm building a autocomplete with Twitter typeahead using an ajax JSON call to my PHP file to get some data but it keeps displaying the following in the dropdown result list:

undefined

undefined

undefined

but when i do:

```
alert(data);
```

I get the right data displayed but somehow the autocomplete list keeps displaying undefined, I've read and tried multiple things by some articles here on StackOverflow, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have to following jquery code:

```
      $('.item-name .typeahead').typeahead(null,{
      source: function (query, process) {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'ajaxItems.php',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'JSON',
          data: 'query=' + query,
          success: function(data) {
            // alert(data);
            process(data);
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

And my ajaxItems.php has the following code for testing purpose:

```
<?PHP
$results = array();

$results[] = 'jeans';
$results[] = 'sweater';

$json =  json_encode($results);
print_r($json);
?>
```

The JSON output is as follows:

```
["jeans","sweater"]
```

I hope someone can shine some light on what I'm doing wrong or point me in the right direction.

*edit*
I am using the following typeahead file:
http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js

Comment: Where can i find this? This is just the typeahead or bootstrap process function to display the results.

Comment: @Rikesh, process() is a part of the typehead code

Comment: Sorry, then im stucked :( It **is** the typeahead originating from twitter bootstrap?

Comment: Yes its the twitter typeahead.

Comment: Is it bootstrap 2.x, 3.x or is it https://blog.twitter.com/2013/twitter-typeaheadjs-you-autocomplete-me ?? Was assuming it was one of the BS version :(

Comment: Its bootstrap 3x and just the official twitter typeahead plugin from twitter.

Comment: I think typehead.js is a mess. Why not take out the small piece of code from a bootstrap 2.3.x that actually was logic an useable and working, and use that instead? Have done that myself several times, when I didnt needed bootstrap but just wanted the typeahead. I have really tried to solve your problem, but I guess you have to create a "bloodHound" and so on, the code and docs is very unclear (to mee). @Amit Joki is quite right that it is failing in the $.map attempt, the code expects some very specific input. Another solution, rewrite _render in typeahead.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problems using `source:` and I ended up using `remote:`.
In your case, it would be something like this:

```
$('.item-name .typeahead').typeahead({
    remote: 'ajaxItems.php?query=%QUERY'
  });
```

Note that I deleted `null` on `typeahead(null,{` since I think it's not necessary but I might be wrong. Obviously, you'll have to use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST` but I think it's much easier this way.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem. To fix it I had to return an array containing key/value pairs with the key 'value' like this:

```
[{'value': 'first', 'value': 'second', 'value': 'third'}]
```

I don't think the [typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md) docs make it clear enough but I believe it is the *displayKey* option which is set to 'value' by default.

Comment: THANK YOU!  I had the same issue.  ASP.Net MVC application returning an array of strings from a LINQ query: "return Json((from i in elementArray select i.StringProperty), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);"  This returns: ["A String", "Another String", "Other String"].  Typehead has only accepted the format: [{Name: "A String"}, {Name: "Another String"}]  This is achieved by changing the LINQ select to an anonymous type: "... select new {Name = i.StringProperty}" and then specifying a displayKey on the typehead declaration: ".typehead({displayKey: 'Name', source: ..."

Comment: This answer has fixed my issue, as well.

Answer (score 3):

The closest answer is ian's though it does not really work (only returns last value). Working answer is :

```
[{'value': 'first'}, {'value': 'second'}, {'value': 'third'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the typeahead is expecting a array with suggestions. Not the JSON !

use `$.makeArray()` like this:

```
success: function(data){
     process($.makeArray(data));
}
```

if it doesn't , may be JSON.parse() should help ?

Mark it as answer if helpful :)

Comment: I tried that, didn't made any different, still undefined undefined.

Comment: It does not work, but you are right - it is there it goes wrong. I have failed to solve the problem with a JSON from $.ajax

Comment: @Adriaan did you try JSON.parse() ?

Comment: @davidkonrad did you try JSON.parse() ?